# Linking selected excel drop down list object to information directly associated to the object

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

Here is the problem. I have created a a drop down list within excel that is linked to a data table. The data table consists of two fields: Product # and Price. The drop down list that I have linked to this table is on a separate sheet that calculates the pricing. The user chooses the product from the drop down list and the associated price is placed in a separate cell where the total price is then calculated. In order for this to work, I made a very large IF formula imbedded with many IF statements. It successfully worked for awhile until I attempted to alter the data table or add additional IF statements beyond what I currently had. Excel would say that the formula was too long. Is there an easier way of accomplishing this? I have searched suggestions and VBA is referenced often, but my knowledge in VBA is basically obsolete. Any suggestions in ways to better build this formula?

```
=IF(C18='data source '!$A$4, 'data source '!$B$4*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$5, 'data source '!$B$5*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$6, 'data source '!$B$6*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$7, 'data source '!$B$7*Pricing!A18))))
```

Comment: Post the formula, there is no way we can optimize it without seeing it

Comment: Its a bit long:

Comment: Edit your original post to add it

Comment: =IF(C18='data source '!$A$4, 'data source '!$B$4*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$5, 'data source '!$B$5*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$6, 'data source '!$B$6*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$7, 'data source '!$B$7*Pricing!A18))))

Comment: This went on for 78 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   =IF(C18='data source '!$A$4, 'data source '!$B$4*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$5, 'data source '!$B$5*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$6, 'data source '!$B$6*Pricing!A18,IF(C18='data source '!$A$7, 'data source '!$B$7*Pricing!A18))))
> ```

Can be much simplified with `VLookup`:

```
=Pricing!A18 * VLOOKUP(C18,'data source '!$A:$B, 2,FALSE)
```

p.s. why dou you have a `space` at the end of the worksheet's name (`'data source '`)? You should think of removing it.

Comment: That works great! Much easier to method. Greatly appreciate your help! The space is automatically placed with no reason. I will probably remove it. Thanks again